# Show/hide 1-5 input boxes based on quantity selected with radio buttons in jQuery, needs cleanup

Tags: jquery, input, coding-style, radio-button

I've hacked together something that works flawlessly but it's really ugly code and I want to learn to clean it up.

Does anyone have a better suggestion then this method? I've used some attribute selectors to cut down the repetition, but I still have to a huge block for each hardware (there are 4 right now). I guess I can use a loop with variables for the hardware?

```
$('input[name="hwA-qty"]').click(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected == 1) { //Hide inputs 2-5
        $('fieldset[id^="hwA"]').hide(); 
    }
    if (selected == 2) { //Show inputs 1 & 2
        $('fieldset#hwA-2').show();
        $('fieldset#hwA-3').hide();
        $('fieldset#hwA-4').hide();
        $('fieldset#hwA-5').hide();
    }
    if (selected == 3) { //Show inputs 1-3
        $('fieldset#hwA-2').show();
        $('fieldset#hwA-3').show();
        $('fieldset#hwA-4').hide();
        $('fieldset#hwA-5').hide();
    }
    if (selected == 4) { //Show inputs 1-4
        $('fieldset#hwA-2').show();
        $('fieldset#hwA-3').show();
        $('fieldset#hwA-4').show();
        $('fieldset#hwA-5').hide();
    }
    if (selected == 5) { //Show all inputs
        $('fieldset[id^="hwA"]').show();
    }
});
$('input[name="hwB-qty"]').click(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected == 1) {
        $('fieldset[id^="hwB"]').hide();
    }
    if (selected == 2) {
        $('fieldset#hwB-2').show();
        $('fieldset#hwB-3').hide();
        $('fieldset#hwB-4').hide();
        $('fieldset#hwB-5').hide();
    }
    if (selected == 3) {
        $('fieldset#hdPvr2').show();
        $('fieldset#hdPvr3').show();
        $('fieldset#hdPvr4').hide();
        $('fieldset#hdPvr5').hide();
    }
    if (selected == 4) {
        $('fieldset#hdPvr2').show();
        $('fieldset#hdPvr3').show();
        $('fieldset#hdPvr4').show();
        $('fieldset#hdPvr5').hide();
    }
    if (selected == 5) {
        $('fieldset[id^="sdPvr"]').show();
    }
}); [...]
```

And here's the html:

```
[...]
<div class="hardwareValidation">

<div class="select">
    <label for="hwA-qty">Quantity</label><br />
    <label>1 <input type="radio" name="hwA-qty" value="1" checked /></label>
    <label>2 <input type="radio" name="hwA-qty" value="2" /></label>
    <label>3 <input type="radio" name="hwA-qty" value="3" /></label>
    <label>4 <input type="radio" name="hwA-qty" value="4" /></label>
    <label>5 <input type="radio" name="hwA-qty" value="5" /></label>
</div>

<fieldset id="hwA-1">
    <div class="input">
        <label for="hwA-1-serial">#1 - Box Serial Number</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="hwA-1-serial" id="hwA-1-serial" />
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hwA-1-override" value=""> Override Validation
        </label>
    </div>
</fieldset>                     

<fieldset id="hwA-2">
    <div class="input">
        <label for="hwA-2-serial">#2 - Box Serial Number</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="hwA-2-serial" id="hwA-2-serial" />
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hwA-2-override" value=""> Override Validation
        </label>
    </div>
</fieldset>

</div> [...]
```

Comment: You could also consider using jQuery to dynamically add as many Input fields as required. They needn't be present in the HTML markup if you don't use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[name="hwA-qty"]').click(function(){
var selected = $(this).val();

for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
   if(i<=selected)$('fieldset#hwA-'+i).show();
   else $('fieldset#hwA-'+i).hide();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, this is great. But it only hides the last of elements.

So if I select "5", 5 inputs show up. Then I click on "2" and only the last input is removed, so 4 are left. I guess I need to add conditions to hide the inputs.

Comment: Wow my bad, made a typo. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `nextAll` traversing method, that selects the following siblings of the matched elements.

```
$('input[name="hwA-qty"]').click(function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $("fieldset[id^='hwA-']").show();
        $("#hwA-" + selected).nextAll().hide();
    });

$('input[name="hwA-qty"]:checked').trigger("click"); // Triggers the click event to set to the initial position
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/GlauberRocha/s4PAG/1/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that method. Haven't heard of it before.